# python find if newline is in string

Tags: python, string, newline

I am trying to find if a "\n" character is in a string using this:

```
if "\n" in errors.text
```

This works fine for a string like "one\ntwo" but when the newline is at the end of the string like "one\n", it doesn't seem to work. I am using selenium to get this string from a website. Is it possible that it is not catching the newline at the end and simply not including it?

Or could this be the problem?

```
fixedText = errors.text.split("\n")[0]
```

I want the fixed text to remove all newlines and only get the first line of text. It works except for the case discussed above

Comment: `"\n" in "one\n"` works fine.

Comment: well im getting the data from a website, so is it possible that it is not catching the newline at the end of the string from the website

Comment: If the string is literally `\ ` and `n`, you should use `"\\n" in errors.text` or `r"\n" in errors.text`

Comment: no its actually just a return

Comment: Is there chance that the page does not contain newline at all?

Comment: no i can edit the page, and i definitely pressed enter after the text so that it went to the next line and then i submitted it

Comment: Try printing the representation of your data to make sure it really is what you think it is, eg `print(repr(errors.text))`. BTW, `\n` is a newline, a (carriage) return is `\r`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you want the fixed text to only be the first line in a string, you can do this:

```
if errors.text: # skips empty strings
    fixedText = errors.text.split("\n")[0]
```

This is because `split()` is reasonably robust:

```
>>> 'a'.split()[0]
'a'
>>> 'a\n'.split()[0]
'a'
>>> 'a\n1'.split()[0]
'a'
>>> ''.split()
[]
```

That last example demonstrates why we check for an empty string before trying to index the resulting `list`.